# Duplicate all rows in sql database table

Tags: sql

I have a table which contains house details called property. I am creating a localised application, and I have a db table called propertylocalised. In this table is held duplicates of the data and culture column e.g.

```
key  culture propertyname

1     en       helloproperty

1     fr       bonjourproperty
```

At the moment  I have all my en culture inserted but I want to duplicate all of those rows and then for every other row insert fr into culture.

I obviously only want to do this once, for the purpose of setting up the localisation.

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table 
SELECT 'fr', propertyname
FROM table
```

assuming you want to duplicate all the existing records which are all 'en'

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into propertylocalised select key,'fr'propertyname from propertylocalised  where culture = 'en'
```

Comment: If 'id' is an autoincrement key, you don't want to insert it.

Comment: @le dorfier as listed in the OP the key is for both languages the same (1). Therefore I would rather expect the same key.

Comment: there are duplicate keys which relate to the property. 

Cheers everyone will try this later. Andy